# how to verify at least XG free space on /var

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, perl, disk-usage

we have the following df -h output

```
[root@trump var]# df -h | grep "/var"

/dev/mapper/vg-lvm_var   101G   85G   17G  84% /var
```

how to verify at least 10G free space on /var in bash/awk/perl one liner

meanwhile I write this syntax :

```
[[ ` df -h | grep "/var" | awk '{print $4}' | sed s'/G//g' ` -lt 10 ]] && echo "/var need at least 10G"
```

but this syntax isn't elegant and ugly and maybe I missed some rules

Comment: First of all `df -BG /var | tail -n1` would be much more reliable an elegant as it will always display Giga Bytes

Comment: And I think your script works well and look relatively fine.

Comment: When you say _10G_ do you mean _10 GB_ or _10 GiB_? They are different amounts and require the use of different flags on `df` or calculations within `awk`. (And yes, `df` is also incorrect in this regard.)

Comment: @roaima df -BG will output in giga bytes while -h will adapt depending on the size. it's just to have always the same behaviour depending on the drive.

Comment: @Kiwy, no that's where you're wrong. `-BG` is Gibibytes (2^n) and `-BGB` is Gigabytes (10^n). This confusion is exactly why I'm asking for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a new enough GNU `df`, you could extract just the available space using the `--output` option. And you could the rest of the comparison with awk:

```
$ df -k --output=avail /var | awk 'NR == 2 && ($1 < 10*2**20) {print "/var need at least 10G"}'
/var need at least 10G
```

Even without that, if you wanted to get a specific filesystem, it's best to do `df /var` instead of `df | grep /var` (unless you want to catch the case of nothing being mounted on `/var`).

For running other commands based on this, with bash, use the `(( ))` arithmetic context:

```
if (( $(df -k --output=avail /var | tail -1) < 10*2**20 ))
then
    log "/var need at least 10G"
fi
```

Comment: what in case we need to print the output by exe log function as the following df -k --output=avail /var | awk 'NR == 2 && ($1 < 10*2**20)  log "/var need at least 10G" , then how to change the awk?

Comment: yes but I only ask how to call function - log from awk in case we have less then 10G

Comment: @Kiwy with that I'd need to strip the G. The `-k` prints in KB and without a suffix.

Comment: @yael sorry, I wrongly tagged you in that comment. See update for running other commands instead.

Comment: ok thx this is what we want